# HAProxy 301 Re-Direct non www to www for root domain

Tags: haproxy, 301-redirect

I am trying to setup HAProxy in a way that when a user goes to example.com, they are 301'ed to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), while keeping intact the users ability to go to sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com, etc, the rule I have been trying to use on the front end is:

`http-request redirect code 301 location www.example.com if {hdr_beg(host) -i example.com}`

but when I run `sudo haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -c` to validate of my cfg file, I get the output: `error detected in frontend 'https-in' while parsing 'http-request redirect' rule : error in condition: no such ACL : '{hdr_beg(host)'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add spaces on both sides of your `{` and `}`:

`http-request redirect code 301 location www.domain1.com if { hdr_beg(host) -i domain1.com }`

The characters aren't part of the command but signify that what's between them is an implicit ACL.

Comment: works perfectly! thanks!